# What is the correct term for the "my own funds\money", specifically for the offcial documents?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I'm a bit confused about the correct term for the `personally owned money` as basically "`money or the amount I have`", like a savings bank account, or just simple girokonto. For example, if in an official form I encounter something like the next question: "Aus welchen Einkünften wird der Lebensunterhalt bestritten?"

And I want to state that I have sufficient funds on my bank accounts. And here I'm a bit confused about the term. In the US I'd just state "own savings" or something along these lines.

In German, can it be something as simple as "`eigene Vermögen`"? Is it a correct term in this case at all? As I understand Vermögen means asses including bank accounts, is that right?

What about "`eigene Ersparnisse`"? Am I assuming that it means "own savings" in the same sense as in the US for example? Meaning savings as my own money saved over time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Own* would translate to something like *privat-*, so you are talking about

- private Ersparnisse or
- Privatvermögen